# How do get rid of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to match key(s) in corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I have created a counterparty session, issuer signs the transaction by passing in its key to the signInitialTransaction. Then when I call the CollectSignaturesFlow to get the buyer's signature, it throws 'Unable to match key(s)' exception.
No idea what went wrong.

This is my initiator flow.

```
package com.template.flows;

@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
public class InitiateTicketMovementFlow extends FlowLogic<String> {
private final String buyer;
private final String issuer;
private final StateRef assetReference;

public InitiateTicketMovementFlow(String buyer, String issuer, String hash, int index) {
    this.buyer = buyer;
    this.issuer = issuer;
    this.assetReference = new StateRef(SecureHash.parse(hash), index);
}

@Override
@Suspendable
public String call() throws FlowException {

    final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);

    AccountInfo issuerAccountInfo = UtilitiesKt.getAccountService(this)
            .accountInfo(issuer).get(0).getState().getData();

    AccountInfo receiverAccountInfo = UtilitiesKt.getAccountService(this)
            .accountInfo(buyer).get(0).getState().getData();

    AnonymousParty buyerAccount = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(receiverAccountInfo));

    QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria()
            .withStateRefs(ImmutableList.of(assetReference));

    StateAndRef<CustomTicket> ticketStateStateAndRef = getServiceHub().getVaultService()
            .queryBy(CustomTicket.class, queryCriteria).getStates().get(0);

    CustomTicket ticketState = ticketStateStateAndRef.getState().getData();

    TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);

    MoveTokensUtilities.addMoveNonFungibleTokens(txBuilder, getServiceHub(),
            ticketState.toPointer(CustomTicket.class), receiverAccountInfo.getHost());

    FlowSession buyerSession = initiateFlow(receiverAccountInfo.getHost());
    buyerSession.send(ticketState.getValuation());

    List<StateAndRef<FungibleToken>> inputs = subFlow(new ReceiveStateAndRefFlow<>(buyerSession));

    List<FungibleToken> moneyReceived = buyerSession.receive(List.class).unwrap(value -> value);

    MoveTokensUtilities.addMoveTokens(txBuilder, inputs, moneyReceived);

    SignedTransaction selfSignedTransaction = getServiceHub().
            signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, ImmutableList.of(issuerAccountInfo.getHost().getOwningKey()));


    SignedTransaction signedTransaction = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(
            selfSignedTransaction, Arrays.asList(buyerSession), Collections.singleton(issuerAccountInfo.getHost().getOwningKey())));

    SignedTransaction stx = subFlow(new FinalityFlow(
            signedTransaction, ImmutableList.of(buyerSession)));

    subFlow(new UpdateDistributionListFlow(stx));

    return "\nTicket is sold to "+ buyer;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives the public key - issuerAccountInfo.getHost().getOwningKey(). Have included this while signing the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It SEEMS like the issue here is that you're getting the buyer account the wrong way? Or that the finality flow call might be off. Take a look at our samples on this.

Maybe try something like this to get your account info

```java
AccountInfo targetAccount = accountService.accountInfo(<STRING NAME OF ACCOUNT >).get(0);
```

src is our corda samples repo: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Accounts/supplychain/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/supplychain/flows/SendShippingRequest.java#L80

Also, note how different the finality calls look like:

https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Accounts/supplychain/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/supplychain/flows/SendShippingRequest.java#L112